# MiniMagick not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, paperclip, minimagick

I am using MiniMagick gem to crop images and then saving them with mongoid paperclip. Everything seems to be working perfectly in development but in production I am getting the error "ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant *Model Name*::MiniMagick)". these are the lines giving the error inside the model:

```
def profile_geometry
  img = MiniMagick::Image.open(avatar.path)
  @geometry = {:width => img[:width], :height => img[:height] }
end
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

EDIT:
Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'quiet_assets'

group :development do
    gem 'awesome_print'
end

group :production do 
    gem 'unicorn'
end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem "mongoid", "~> 4.0.0.beta1"
gem "devise"
gem "mongoid-paperclip", :require => "mongoid_paperclip"
gem "cancan"
gem "simple-rss"
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'rvm-capistrano'

gem 'stripe'
```

Comment: Can you list your Gemfile?

Comment: install imagemagick on your production server and then restart it

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I am running unicorn with nginx, restarted both multiple times. I also have imagemagick installed on rackspace. I can access MiniMagick in rails c in production too.

Answer (score 0):

Well it was the restart that did it. After restarting nginx and unicorn several times I restarted the rackspace server completely and everything is fine now.